# Does @Html.ValidationSummary work for client side validation in MVC3 or MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false) 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "xxx")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        action,
        "Menus",
        null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = success
        }, new { @id = "menuForm" }))
{
    <dl>
    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order)</dt>
    <dd>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Order)</dd>
    <dd>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Order)</dd>
    </dl>
```

When I enter an Order value of 999 then I immediately get client side validation that shows me an error message just after the Order Text box. However nothing shows up in the Html.ValidationSummary area. Is it possible to use this with client side validation?

Here is my model:

```
public class Menu
{
    [Range(0, 99, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
    [DisplayName("Order")]
    public int Order { get; set; }
```

My web config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain but the validation summary I can find in the MVC 3 default application is within the Form. Maybe because your validation summaries are sitting outside of the form they don't get updated.
What happens when you move the Validation summary inside the form?

From:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false) 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "xxx")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        action,
        "Menus",
        null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = success
        }, new { @id = "menuForm" }))
{
    <dl>
    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order)</dt>
    <dd>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Order)</dd>
    <dd>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Order)</dd>
    </dl>
```

To:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        action,
        "Menus",
        null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = success
        }, new { @id = "menuForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false) 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "xxx")
    <dl>
    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order)</dt>
    <dd>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Order)</dd>
    <dd>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Order)</dd>
    </dl>
```

Comment: I tried this and it's just the same. still does not work. What I did do was to move the Html.ValidationMessageFor to the top just inside of the form. This works but I don't really want to have many Html.ValidationMessageFor all one after the other at the top of the page.

Comment: Quote: `What I did do was to move the Html.ValidationMessageFor to the top just inside of the form.` That's what I asked you try as seen in the code following the `To: ` in which the validation summaries are inside the form. So I don't know what you mean by `I tried this and it's just the same. still does not work.`

Comment: Regarding `but I don't really want to have many Html.ValidationMessageFor all one after the other at the top of the page` that's a design choice at least you have now solved the issue of why your validation summary didn't show up. How to present and style them is another story I guess.