# in MVC4 MVC3 ValidationSummary() div no longer auto hides

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

We upgraded to MVC 4 and learned through this thread [Does @Html.ValidationSummary work for client side validation in MVC3 or MVC4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210197/does-html-validationsummary-work-for-client-side-validation-in-mvc3-or-mvc4) the ValidationSummary has to be placed inside the form instead of right before it. Validation summary works again, except under MVC 3 the div "automagicaly" was not present until there were errors. Now the div is visible and right in our faces. We can set it to display:none, but there seems to be no hook to display it when we want to.

```
<div class="errormessagebox" >
    @Html.ValidationSummary(@OurHelpers.VALIDATION_HEADER)
</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering why do you need it inside <form> ?

Comment: According to another SO thread, ValidationSummary now has to be inside the form in MVC4. In any case I could not get it working until I did that. I was not involved in getting this running on MVC3, so I don't know how decisions were made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it like this, and I don't see anything unless there is some error.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Account", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, null))
    {       
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)   
      //other elements
    }
```

maybe you have overridden some ul or li elements css in your site? try this code and of doesn't work check the css you have for your site.

Comment: Now I just need to devise producing the wrapping <div> with a helper.