# Html.ValidationSummary and Ajax.BeginForm Best Practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

When some of the validation errors are client side and the others are server side, the client side errors goes into the `@Html.ValidationSummary` placeholder in the main view while the server side ones goes into the `@Html.ValidationSummary` which located on the action partial view.

If i'm not specifying `@Html.ValidationSummary` as part of the form action partial view, no server side errors shown at all.

how can i merge all the errors (client and server side) into one div located outside of the UpdateTargetId element?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PartialViewAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AjaxResult"}))
{
        <div class="ValidationSummary">
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        </div>

           <div class="ChartCriteriaSideBox">      
                <div>
                    <ul class="none">
                        <li>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.datesRange.PeriodTypeId, (int)DatesRange.PeriodType.RecentMonth, new { @checked = "checked" }) Recent Month
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.datesRange.PeriodTypeId, (int)DatesRange.PeriodType.RecentYear) Recent Year
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.datesRange.PeriodTypeId, (int)DatesRange.PeriodType.BetweenDates) Range
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210197/does-html-validationsummary-work-for-client-side-validation-in-mvc3-or-mvc4

Comment: Have you specified two different ValidationSummary? if yes then are both of them in the same form?

Comment: might help you
http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2013/08/part-86-validationsummary-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Orif Khodjaev's answer was very helpful but with a little change:

instead of using DOMSubtreeModified event i am now using AjaxForm OnComplete event. DOMSubtreeModified event is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the ways to achieve the desired result.
In your main view you should have a structure like this:

```
<div id="MainValidationSummary">
  @Html.ValidationSummary()
  <div id="PartialValidationSummary"></div>
</div>
```

You can make AjaxResult validation summary invisible if you want, but don't delete it! Data from the server must be updated there.:

```
#ajaxresult{
  display: none;
}
```

And add this event listener to your view:

```
$('#ajaxresult').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  $('#PartialValidationSummary').html($('#ajaxresult').html());
);
```

I've updated the code so that the event actually fired. Unfortunately, it will work only in IE8+ and will output warning to the console suggesting the use of newer API that works only with IE11+

Comment: Are you sure that the event change should work in a div element? i tried but the event not fired... Could you suggest?

Comment: @Omtechguy sorry, I was mistaken about the event, I've update the answer